# Почему изображения в nginx передаются в типе text/html?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, сервер, администрирование

Фуллстек приложение, на локальной машине все работало отлично. После посадки на nginx и получения ssl все работает за исключением одного, изображения из статики достаются в неправильном типе,а именно text/html:[image: images with content-type text/html]

## Вот конфиги:

### /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
 # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascri>

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
# 
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
 upstream client-upstream {
    server    0.0.0.0:3000;
    keepalive 15;
}

upstream back-upstream {
    server    0.0.0.0:5000;
    keepalive 15;
}

server {
    server_name DOMAINNAME.ru www.DOMAINNAME.ru;
    server_tokens off;
    client_max_body_size 1000M;
    root /var/www/prod/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://client-upstream;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Host $host;

    }

    location /api {
         proxy_pass http://back-upstream;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAINNAME.ru/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/DOMAINNAME.ru/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = DOMAINNAME.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
    server_name DOMAINNAME.ru www.DOMAINNAME.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**P.S. Приложение: ReactJS клиент, NodeJS api, 2 процесса на pm2, иерархия:**

```
client
        src 
             components 
                      some_component.js (достаются в виде https://DOMAIN.RU/file_name.jpg)
server
         static (изображения хранятся здесь)
```

Comment: Смею предположить что у него какие-то проблемы в `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;`  он не понимает какой тип предоставить для твоего файла и берёт по умолчанию `text/html`, либо у тебя суффикс отсутствует либо самого миме суффикса нету на сервере.

Comment: mime.types полностью стандартный, проверял на наличие

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение проблемы. Запросы оставил точно такими же, приложение перенес в **var/www/html**, далее в конфиге **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default** прописал

```
location ~* \.(jpeg|jpg|mp4)$ {
     root /var/www/html/project/server/static;
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, это ответ на ваш вопрос? Если да, то конечно логично отдавать статику через nginx, а не слать все запросы бэкенду.

Comment: Если это ответ на свой же вопрос, то тогда рекомендую закрыть его, отметив данный ответ как верный (галочка слева от текста). Ну и прописать также, что данная мера помогла в решении проблемы, а то сейчас это не очень очевидно